# Create a String[] between the range of year

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a string array between From and To input.
like From = 2000 To = 2003

I want to create a string[] as below:

> ```
> string[] arrayYear = new string[]{"2000","2001","2002","2003"};
> ```

Is there any easy way of building it dynamically for any range of year?

Please suggest me.

Comment: If you want that to be really configurable you should consider adding that to a database or a configuration file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range`

```
int startYear = 2000, endYear = 2004;
string[] arrayYear = Enumerable.Range(startYear, endYear - startYear + 1).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: You are awesome .. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.Range()`

```
var arrayList = Enumerable.Range(2000, 2015-2000+1).ToList();
string[] arrayYear = arrayList.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: `I want to create a string array...`